# How can I quickly replace separate variable declarations with in-line declarations in a function?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a task to refactor some code, and one of the thing I need to do is replace many instances of separate variable declaration with in-line declaration as part of a function. It's taking a long time to do manually, and I wonder if there is a faster way in IntelliJ

```java
    public void getUrlOutputNotNull() {
        final Paginator objectUnderTest = new Paginator();
        final String actual = objectUnderTest.getUrl();
        Assert.assertEquals("", actual);
    }
```

is supposed to become

```java
    public void getUrlOutputNotNull() {
        final Paginator objectUnderTest = new Paginator();
        Assert.assertEquals("", objectUnderTest.getUrl());
    }
```

I'm doing it all manually currently. Is there a way in IntelliJ to automate this process or at least do it faster?

Answer (score 2):

You may inline the variable. For this put the cursor within the *actual*:

```
Assert.assertEquals("", actu<cursor>al);
```

and press Refactor | Inline variable (or Alt + Cmd + N on Mac OS).